# How can I assign contrast values to each pixel of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, image-processing

I want to be able to assign a contrast value to each pixel of an image using javascript (if this isn't possible with javascript, which language should I use instead?). So for example, a black pixel surrounded by white pixels would have a contrast value of 100%:

[image]

I also need this to work for coloured pixels. So if there's a bright red pixels surrounded by bright blue pixels, it would have a high contrast value. If there was a very dark red pixel surrounded by black pixels, it would have a low contrast value.

Comment: you can easily do it with `canvas` and reading the pixel data. Out there are lots of useful information on how to manipulate image data using JS, HTML5 and the canvas element

Comment: **You need to specify more your question**: In your colour example,what are the levels of the three channels for each pixel? Do you need to consider all the channels in the comparison or only the opposite channels?